# difference in css selectors?

Tags: css

what is the difference between both of this css selectors as both of them give me same effect then makes different using '>'

1. .abc > p
2. .xyz p

```css
.abc > p {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.xyz p {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<div class="abc">
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
    <h2>My name is Donald</h2>
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
</div>

<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>

<p>I will not be styled.</p>

<div class="xyz">
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
    <h2>My name is Donald</h2>
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But basically - `.abc > p` will select only the `p` tags that their direct parent is `.abc` while `xyz p` will select any `p` elements that are inside `.xyz` (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thanks all for the Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

div p

```
Selects all <p> elements inside <div> elements
```

div > p

```
Selects all <p> elements where the parent is a <div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `.abc > p {}` would apply to all `p` elements who are DIRECT descendants of `.abc`:

```
<div class="abc">
    <p>I'm affected</p>
    <div class="test">
        <p>I'm not</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using `.xyz p {}` applies to ALL p elements within `.xyz`, whether they're direct descendants, grandchildren, great-great grandchildren, etc:

```
<div class="xyz">
    <p>I'm affected</p>
    <div class="test">
        <p>I'm affected</p>
        <div class="anothertest">
            <p>I'm also affected</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think effected should be affected. But the actual solution is correct

Comment: @AdamHughes Corrected spelling just now - cheers for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The `>` symbol targets any direct children of a specific section, in your case `.abc`. Without it, the style also applies to any sub-children of that class.